Flutter Supabase client - query on jsonb array of json objects not working
I have a Flutter web app that is querying a Supabase database via the Flutter Supabase client library.
One of my queries is not working when I try to query a jsonb column called 'tags' that holds an array of json records.  For example:
[
  {
    "id": 22,
    "title": "test5",
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "title": "test6",
  }
]

When I construct a query to find all JSON records with the ID 22, the query returns nothing.
The fetch clause is like:
.eq('tags->id', 22)

The URL created by the client app includes a parameter like:
&tags-%3Eid=eq.22

Any suggestions?
Follow up question:
Further to some initial feedback I changed my jsonb 'tags'column to store the data in the following json data model:
{
  "tagEntries": [
    {
      "id": 22,
      "title": "test5",
      "userUid": "cc1b9ad0-c24b-4756-a884-7b8a5e18a5fb"
    }
  ]
}

When I try to query on the json data I'm using....
.eq('tags->tagEntries[*].id',22)

... and it still does not work.
Any suggestions??

I think that .eq('tags->id', 22) doesn't because of data scheme. I bet it would've worked if your scheme looked like this:
{
  "tags": {
    "id": 22,
    "title": "test5"
  }
}

But, your json is not and object which field may be accessed like this, but an array. In that case, I guess, it's worth to try filter instead of eq, like this:
.filter('tags', 'cs', '{"id": 22}')

filter uses special (I would say "raw") Postgres syntax, it gives a little bit more flexibility, but should be used carefully.
cs stands for contains meaning json will be filtered to values (arrays, in that case) which has specific field with specific value.

Thanks for the feedback, and I now understand the JSON data model aspect.  But the docs found at https://postgrest.org/en/stable/references/api/tables_views.html#vertical-filtering suggest that my approach should work.    The question boils down to how you would reference a top level json array in the supported naming convention.

I've tried using tags->>[*]->>id but his fails with a parsing error
